# Dialog Box for Login with Social Media Accounts

Tags: iphone, facebook, listbox, dialog, integration

I have been looking for the ways to integrate facebook, twitter or email in my iphone App but I didn't find the way to do the dialog box which proposes these previous options...

Here is what I am looking to do

[image: Dialog Box]
<sub>(source: [fonearena.com](http://www.fonearena.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/2009/06/iphone-3gs-share.jpg))</sub>

It seems like an alert view but it sure isn't ... anyone knows how to do that ? (I guess it is a predefined object) ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a UIActionSheet.

Heres the Class Reference:
http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/uikit/reference/UIActionSheet_Class/Reference/Reference.html

Answer (score 0):

It is an `UIActionSheet`. If you are looking for Twitter code then look at my Twitter code for the iPhone. It was specifically designed for 'Share' functionality:

http://github.com/st3fan/iphone-twitter/